# how to loop data json/return one by one/split one by one

Tags: java, jquery, json

i have data json like this:

```
{"output":{"id":"1","nama":"one"}},
{"output":{"id":"2","nama":"two"}},
{"output":{"id":"3","nama":"three"}}
```

how to make the data json return one by one.

example result like this:

loop 1

```
{"output":{"id":"1","nama":"one"}}
```

loop 2

```
{"output":{"id":"2","nama":"two"}}
```

loop 3

```
{"output":{"id":"3","nama":"three"}}
```

thanks,hope someone can answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for `each loop`?

```js
var data = [{"output":{"id":"1","nama":"one"}},
{"output":{"id":"2","nama":"two"}},
{"output":{"id":"3","nama":"three"}}];

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    console.log(item);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `.each` loop, but you need to have your data in an array using the `[]` notation:

```js
var jsonData = [
  {"output":{"id":"1","nama":"one"}},
  {"output":{"id":"2","nama":"two"}},
  {"output":{"id":"3","nama":"three"}}
 ];


$.each(jsonData , function(k, v) {
    console.log ("key",k,"value", v);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```